# Read and write to the registry with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, registry

I made a game and I would like to store the high score and other values in the windows registry. It's made in VB.NET. Could someone give me a sample code example of simple reading and writing to the registry.

Thanks

Comment: Man, I'm glad people weren't that harsh when I posted my first few questions.  Lighten up, folks.

Answer (score 4):

You must open Registry sub Key before read or write. Then you can read or write

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
Dim Value As Object
regKey =My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB_and_VBA_Program_Settings", True)
'Here u can read value of AppName
Value = regKey.GetValue("AppName", "Default Value")
'Or u can write the value
  value=regkey.setValue("AppName", "myApp")
regKey.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply...

```
  Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

  Dim s As String

  SaveSetting("(AppName)", "(SectionName)", "(Key)", "(Your Value)")

  s = GetSetting("(AppName)", "(SectionName)", "(Key)", "(Default Value)")
```

Replace (AppName), (SectionName), (Key) with appropriate values. The data will be saved in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\(AppName)

Comment: That worked for me.  SaveSetting is less fussy about registry read/write permissions because it is writing in a controlled way to a well defined place in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WindowsRegistry04262005045814AM/WindowsRegistry.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm more comfortable with C#, but it's pretty straightforward with VB.NET too.  Here's an example of how to [write to the registry](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=174), and another example of how to [read from the registry](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=4487).  Don't forget to import the Microsoft.Win32 namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use registry.getvalue and registry.setvalue. Here are a couple of examples used for default file types:

```
Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes" & "\" & fileFormatExt(i), "", "error")

Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\" & FileType, "", appTag) ' set new value, overwrite any other, creates key if not there.
```