# insert a variable value in Regwrite line

Tags: vb.net, variables, registry

Hi I have a variable creativly named VAR1 I need to insert the variables value in my regkey where it says 140
 how do i do this....

```
    Private Sub OKAY_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OKAY.Click

    Dim wshshell

    wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshshell.RegWrite("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer\NoDrives", 140, "REG_DWORD")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `wshshell` when you can use the framework, look at one of the many examples of how to do it, already on the web. [For instance](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/registry_with_vb.aspx). Or look at one of the many duplicate questions [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250455/read-and-write-to-the-registry-with-vb-net).

Comment: nice but this method works best for me, unless ofcause it is without doubt the root cause of my problem...